# 'watch' command will not execute, Exec format error

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I'm trying to monitor a file that will get downloaded by another process using `ls -haltd`. When I run the `watch` command the execution fails.

e.g.

```
$ watch ls -halt myfile.txt
-bash: /usr/bin/watch: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I've checked to make sure there are no aliases for `watch` (there are no aliases for anything)

I've checked the binary with `file`

```
$ file `which watch`
/usr/bin/watch: ELF 64-bit (SYSV)
```

and I've verified my OS as

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux valhalla 5.4.0-1053-raspi #60-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 11 07:18:29 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The machine is built of the same image as many others and I'm not having this issue elsewhere. Before I go off modifying the config of a production server, any thoughts on the cause of this?

Comment: try `watch 'ls -halt myfile.txt'` ... ie. pass the `ls -halt myfile.txt` as a single parameter instead of as multiple parameters  ; ie. your command caused `-halt` and `myfile.txt` to not be part of the `ls` command you gave as a parameter but get treated as extra operands of `watch`...

Comment: Is `ELF 64-bit (SYSV)` the *complete* output of the `file` command? does it not mention an interpreter at all?

Comment: Just tried single quoting it, no joy using single or double quotes; $ watch 'ls -halt myfile.txt'
-bash: /usr/bin/watch: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: yes @steeldriver that is the entire output. On a different (PopOS) box it reports as a ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable. AFIK the watch command is an executable in all cases (not a script)

Comment: A bit of source code spelunking reveals that the watch command will consume everything after the last option as the command, no quotes necessary; https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/watch.c#L879

Comment: @IndividualRich unfortunately I don't have an ARM64 machine to play with - I wonder if it is worth just re-installing the procps package in case the binary got replaced or corrupted somehow? (`apt install --reinstall procps`)